Firebase Authentication: emailVerified becomes false after manually adding to a user who signed up via Google with the same email
I'm working on a project using Firebase Authentication and have encountered an unexpected behavior regarding the emailVerified field. When a user signs up using Google OAuth, their email is automatically marked as verified in Firebase, as expected. However, I've noticed an issue that arises when I later manually add the same email address. After adding the email address manually, the emailVerified field switches from true to false for that user. This behavior is perplexing, as I would expect the email verification status to remain true given that the user initially signed up through Google.
Is there a way I can keep the emailVerified as true since both the emails are same?
// user previously signup via GoogleAuth.
// below email is same as GoogleAuth
 const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, newPassword);
 await linkWithCredential(currentUser, credential);


Hey there. What do you mean by "when I later manually add the same email address"? Are referring when adding the same email address with a different provider?

i'm trying to set the password to the same email so that user can choose to login via google Auth or email and password. when i set the password, emailVerified becomes false.
